# What mathematics shows that time goes backwards when going faster than C?

Tags: special-relativity

From what I see time should be imaginaty number when v > c and not a negative nimber.

Comment: Going faster than c is not a part of relativity? Perhaps there are several ways to get to a point though, with some ways shorter than others. Not sure if they have ruled out this. Space folding into itself at different points.

Comment: You are correct, no math shows this. Nothing moves faster than light. This is not a technical limitation, but a limitation of the hyperbolic geometry where space and time are not independent from each other. Speeds faster than light simply don't exist in the geometry of our spacetime.

Comment: [Somehow related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21485/the-speed-of-tachyons)

Comment: You are reversing causality.  No mathematics needed.